# Using find command to create ctags (for code navigation)

Tags: linux, emacs, find, ctags

I have a big code repository for a project and I'm trying to make it searchable via emacs TAGS. So I go into the main directory and I try using this command to generate the tags:

```
find . -name *.[chsS] | xargs etags -
```

However I get the response "find: No match."

When I just type the "find" command on its own, it lists all the code files and subdirectories with more code files that I wish to tag.

How can I make this work? Just to make clear, I want to be able to use the emacs M-. and M-* to navigate around code tags in a big repository.

Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try enclosing the name in single-quotes so the shell won't interpret the star as a wildcard: `find . -name '*.[chsS]' | xargs etags -`

Comment: Or backquote it `find . -name \*.[chsS] | xargs etags -`

Answer (score 2):

I call shannanigans on your claim that this works:

```
find . -name *.[chsS]
```

Here, your interactive shell would expand "*.[chsS]" into a list of files, and the first one would be accepted as the "name" parameter.  But find will try to interpret the second file as an option, and it won't be valid.

The lesson here is to quote wildcards passed to find either with single-quotes, double-quotes, or backslash.

Comment: the way this *could* work is that some shells can be configured to pass a glob through as an argument when the glob doesn't match anything.  So in a case when this command is run in a directory which contains no .c, .h, .s, .S files

Answer (score 0):

For C and header files using ctags tool,

```
find . -name \*.[ch] | xargs ctags
```

This command will include the source file with extension `.c` and `.h`

Answer (score 0):

If you use ctags developed at https://ctags.io

```
ctags --languages=C,Asm --kinds-C=+p -e -R
```

may generate TAGS file.